# MATLAB - Too many output arguments error need help

Tags: matlab

I don't really know how to explain what I'm after without an example. I guess the title could be better but I'm not sure how to describe the issue.

I've got the following function

```
function [x,y] = f(z)
z = 3;
x = z.*[2;1];
y = z.*[1 2; 3 4];
end
```

Now I want to use f(z) as a function handle in the next function as the input "func" and I want x and y back from f(z) to use separately in the 2nd function.

```
function a = h(func, b)
[x,y] = func;
b = 2;
a = b.*y;
end
```

But I get the following error when trying to do so

```
>> h(f(3),2)
Too many output arguments.

Error in h (line 2)
[x,y] = func;
```

How do I get x and y back separately? This doesn't seem to be working.

```
[x,y] = func;
```

I also tried:

```
x = func(1)
y = func(2)
```

but this assigns x to the first index of x and y to the 2nd index of x. How do I get it to do what I want, whilst keeping the input name as "func" and using f(z) which returns 2 outputs?

Comment: writing h(f(3),2) calls the function f with argument 3 and then sends the result into h which if it has several outputs will be **only the leftmost output**. what you want is probably to send the handle f and the input separately and make the call inside h?

Comment: to avoid only getting the leftmost output returned by accident you can encapsulate outputs into a "cell" which is like an array but where you can store arbitrary matlab objects in each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function a = h(func,arg, b)
 [x,y] = func(arg); % this should assign both outputs
```

and the call to h

```
 h(f,3,2) % only writing f without () will send the handle and not execute and send the result into h.
```

---

I am not able to reproduce your error. But there does exist a quite large community at mathworks site with questions and answers.

---

Another thing you can try if you get tired of how multiple outputs behaves is to build a cell and to return it, you can use { and } to build a cell:

```
function [o] = f(z)
```

and at the end of function f:

```
o = {x,y}; % writing variables in { and } separated by , builds a "cell" object.
```

you can learn more about cells by typing "help cell"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd change your example:

```
h(@() f(3), 2)

function [x,y] = f(z)
  x = z .* [2;1];
  y = z .* [1,2; 3,4];
end

function a = h(func, b)
  [x,y] = func();
  a = b .* y;
end
```

Notable points:

- I removed the assignments to parameters `z` and `b` inside the functions.  I assumed those assignments were the remnants of some experimentation.
- What you want, if I'm not mistaken, is to partially evaluate `f` for `z` equal to 3 and then pass the resulting (anonymous) function of no arguments to `h`.  This is done with `@() f(3)`.  The expression `f(3)` does not evaluate to a function handle, as noted by @mathreadler.
- To call `func` in `h` we need a pair of parentheses, as in `func()`.  Otherwise, we try to assign one function handle to two targets, which is an error.

The result produced by MATLAB for the code above is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 12 \\
18 & 24
\end{bmatrix}
$$